# Is this statement about n-tuples incomplete?

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics

To prove the following statement is an exercise in my real analysis book.

There are,
$$\frac{r!}{r_1!r_2!...r_n!}$$
ordered n-tuples of integers $(i_1,i_2,i_3,...,i_n)$ that contain $r_1$ ones, $r_2$ twos,...,$r_n$ n's.

What is $r$ here? is it to be assumed that $r_1+r_2+r_3...+r_n=r$? It seems strange however, since $(i_1,i_2,...,i_n)$ contain $n$ integers, is it not the case that $r_1+r_2+r_3...+r_n=n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$r$ is the number of symbols. The symbols are going from $1$ to $n.$ For example, take $n=5,$ the string $12321$ has $r=5$ symbols, where one is $r_1=2$ times, two is $r_2=2$ times, $r_3=1$ and $r_4=0,r_5=0$(there are no fours nor fives in the string). So, $r_1+r_2+r_3+r_4=5=r.$ 
Formally, $$r_j=|\{m\in [n]:i_m=j\}|.$$

It seems then that this is just the case that $r=n$(typo, perhaps) In general, the result is for $(i_1,\cdots ,i_r)$ for general $r.$